# Show that S (a subset of V) is contained in span(S)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

Let $\text{span}(S) = \lbrace v \in V \mid v\ \text{is a linear combination of vectors in}\ S\rbrace$.

I need to show that $S$ is contained within $\text{span}(S)$. I know if $S$ is nonempty, $0$ is an element of $\text{span}(S)$. Is there any way to build upon that fact in order to prove that $S$ is contained within $\text{span}(S)$? Should we show that $\text{span}(S)$ is a subset of $V$ in order to say that $S$ is contained in $\text{span}(S)$?

> **Definition 2.1 (Span)**. Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Let $S \subseteq V$ be any subset of vectors. The span of $S$, denoted $\text{span}(S)$ is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $S$. That is
>   $$
> \text{span}(S) := \{v  \in V \mid v\ \text{is a linear combination of vectors in}\ S\}\\
> = \{v \in V \mid \exists c_1, \ldots, c_m \in F,\  v_1, \ldots v_m \in S,\ \text{s.t.}\ v = c_1 v1 + \ldots + c_m v_m \}
> $$

Can something similar to this answer the above question?

Let $W$ be a subspace containing $S$. We need to show that $W$ contains
$\text{span}(S)$. This is obvious. Since $W$ is a subspace, it is closed under
addition and scalar multiplication. Therefore, if $W$ contains $S$, it must
contain every linear combinations of elements of $S$. But the set of all
possible linear combinations of elements of $S$ is precisely $\text{span}(S)$.

Comment: How do you define the span of a set?  Could you edit your question and add the "textbook definition" that you're working with?

Comment: Can you realize an element in $S$ as linear combination of elements in $S$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I added my textbook's definition.

Comment: @AndreaMori What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: @Emily: By definition the span of $S$ is the set of all vectors that are linear combinations of vectors in $S$, thus in order to show that $S$ is contained in its span, you need to show that every element in $S$ is linear combination of elements in $S$. Can you do that?

Comment: Try setting each of the coefficients to zero except for one, which you set equal to $1$.  What is the resulting vector?

Comment: @AndreaMori I can try... I'm really struggling with linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any element $ s \in S $ is trivially a linear combination of elements from $ S $, since, obviously $ s = 1*s $.

You can imagine span(S) as the set obtained by taking elements of S and "putting them together" in every possible way. Any vector from S can be obtained if you just take it and no other vectors. So it's in span(S) and $ S \subset span(S) $.